# modify string with standard delimiters into defined output pattern and use to assign value labels

Tags: r

I recently learned about the {[`codebook`](https://rubenarslan.github.io/codebook/articles/codebook_tutorial.html#variable-labels)} and {[`labelled`](https://rubenarslan.github.io/codebook/articles/codebook_tutorial.html#variable-labels)} packages for annotating datasets. [This codebook tutorial](https://rubenarslan.github.io/codebook/articles/codebook_tutorial.html#variable-labels) demonstrates an interesting approach for using a built-in function to label all **variables** at once from a separate meta data table.

I don't see a similar approach for assigning **value** labels, but I think it should be possible.

Here's a toy dataset (`df`) with a separate dataframe of meta data (`meta`):

```
meta <- tibble(variable = c("var1", "var2"),
               valueLabels = c("1, cat | 2, dog",
                               "0, blue | 1, green | 2, red"))

#variable valueLabels                
#  <chr>    <chr>                      
#1 var1     1, cat | 2, dog            
#2 var2     0, blue | 1, green | 2, red

df <- tibble(var1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
             var2 = c(0, 1, 2, 0))
#   var1  var2
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0
#2     2     1
#3     1     2
#4     2     0
```

Using the `labelled` package, I could manually label each item as follows:

```
library(labelled)
val_labels(df$var1) <- c("cat" = 1, "dog" = 2)
val_labels(df$var2) <- c("blue" = 0, "green" = 1, "red" = 2)

df$var1
#<labelled<double>[4]>
#[1] 1 2 1 2

#Labels:
# value label
#     1   cat
#     2   dog
```

It would be tedious and error prone to manually code this for a large dataset. Thus, my questions:

1. Given a string like `"1, cat | 2, dog"`, can we turn it into `"cat" = 1, "dog" = 2` with a custom function?
2. Assuming these strings live inside a dataframe like `meta` as shown here, what would be the best approach to apply this function to every variable in some `df` (that has a string instruction in `meta`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below option returns a `list` of `key/value` columns from the 'valueLabels' `split` by 'variable' column of 'meta'.  Then, use `imap` to loop over the dataset 'df', extract the `list` element based on the column name, assign the labels to the corresponding columns and return a tibble with the suffix `_dfr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(labelled)
library(tibble)
lst1 <- meta %>%
     separate_rows(valueLabels, sep="\\s+\\|\\s+") %>% 
     separate(valueLabels, into = c('value1', 'value2'),
           convert = TRUE) %>% 
     {split(.[-1], .$variable)}

imap_dfr(df, ~ {
      val_labels(.x) <- lst1[[.y]] %>% 
                select(2:1) %>%
                deframe
   .x})
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#       var1      var2
#  <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>
#1   1 [cat] 0 [blue] 
#2   2 [dog] 1 [green]
#3   1 [cat] 2 [red]  
#4   2 [dog] 0 [blue]
```

---

It can be done with `base R` as well with `strsplit`

```
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(meta$valueLabels, "\\s+\\|\\s+"), 
    function(x) with(read.csv(text =x, header = FALSE)[2:1], setNames(V1, V2)))
df[] <- Map(function(x, y) {val_labels(x) <- y; x}, df, lst1)
```

Comment: could you give a hint to how to generalize this `"\\s+\\|\\s+"` to the case where the value label is multiple words? For example,  `val_labels(df$var2) <- c("blue" = 0, "candy apple green" = 1, "light red" = 2)`

Comment: i had the wrong diagnosis. `"\\s+\\|\\s+"` was not the offending line. i needed to add `sep=","` to `separate()`.